# gfortranコンパイル時のオプションについて

Tags: fortran

g95で下記のような内容をコンパイルする場合、オプションとして次のようにしていました。

-fsloppy-char

g95が使えなくなり、gfortranでg77のコードを同様にオプションを付してコンパイルしたのですが、
「-fsloppy-char」に相当するオプションを見つけられませんでした。

教えて頂けますと有難く存じます。

記

-fsloppy-char

Suppress errors when writing non-character data to character descriptors, and allow
comparisons between INTEGER and CHARACTER variables.